# what is the meaning of "他来了请闭眼"

Tags: translation

It is a TV series title I've been watching recently. Maybe closing the eyes is an idiom that I don't understand?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Me,_If_You_Dare_%28TV_Series%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the idiom is adapted from the [Chinese version](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%80%E6%89%8B_(%E6%B8%B8%E6%88%8F)) of [Mafia (party game)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_(party_game)).
Players close their eyes "at night". 
In the Chinese version of the game, it's "天黑了请闭眼" (It's dark, please close your eyes (waiting for something to happen next).).
Also, I think the expression “他来了请闭眼” (He comes, please close your eyes (waiting for something to happen next).) contains elements of burlesque or joke.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a conditional statement: When he comes, please close your eyes.
Please note that “了” does not necessarily mark the statement for a past event. In this case it marks "future completion". Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. Instead of When he comes please close your eyes, I would suggest "He is here. Please close you eyes."

Comment: Instead of leaving a comment to clarify it, you can **edit** you post.